# Wait for async task on application exit from UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parse-platform, task-parallel-library

I'm writing an UI app. If some exception happens I need to do some work before application exit. 
So I subscribed to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleException;
```

`HandleException` method performs async saving to remote(because there are no sync api).

```
private void HandleException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (var user in UsersCollection.ToArray())
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var session in user.Sessions.ToArray())
            {
                try
                {
                    SaveSessionAsync(session).Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.Error("Can't save session: " + session, e);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error("Can't save sessions of user " + user, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Before application exit I need to be sure that I saved all sessions(tried, at least). But if I put `Wait()` there I get a deadlock and application never stops. 
As far as I know, `await` may help me in normal situation(when I'm in UI thread but not in app termination state), but `await` does not awaits on application exit. So my saving tasks may be aborted. But I need them to finish.

Is there a way of waiting for guaranteed finish of `SaveSessionAsync` task without creating a deadlock?

BTW: SaveSessionAsync has Parse.com API inside

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the issue, it's impossible to know what a good answer to the question would be. However, generally speaking the `UnhandledException` event isn't there for exception handling per se. It plays a similar role as finalizers, i.e. as a backstop to buggy code. You should be awaiting your async operation inside a `try`/`catch` block so that the exception _isn't_ unhandled. Then you can do your cleanup work in the `catch` clause there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only used part of the syntax you need to run it in a non-`async` method. Utilizing `Task.Run()` will run it in an asynchronous fashion without having to use `await`.

Try this:

```
Task.Run(() => SaveSessionAsync(session)).Wait();
```